# Using Sendbird with redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist, sendbird

I am using [sendbird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendbird) chat in react-native android app. In efforts to improve chat perceived speed I am letting users see previous data & load updates async (not showing loader).

I am using sendbird with `redux-persist` & saving entire `Chat` reducer object. Most reducer code is taken from https://github.com/sendbird/SendBird-JavaScript/tree/master/react-native-redux-sample.

Data is being pulled back from persisted state successfully. But it fails while rendering. Functions like `isUserMessage`, `isFileMessage`, etc do not exist. 
I tried finding where these functions are defined, but could not find anything except the [type definitions](https://github.com/sendbird/SendBird-SDK-JavaScript/blob/40e368cfd2d2f447da8a5e8a0150a20968994896/SendBird.d.ts#L321-L325).

Is there a good way to construct entire redux state back from serialized JSON?

Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use SendBird's SyncManager SDK with your application to manage chat data synchronization and allow for local caching in your application.

Please see the React Native Redux sample with the SyncManager SDK here:
https://github.com/sendbird/SendBird-JavaScript/tree/master/react-native-redux-syncmanager-sample

That said, here is the official JavaScript API documentation for the BaseMessage class that includes the `isUserMessage` and `isFileMessage` methods to help in determining the message type:
https://sendbird.github.io/core-sdk-javascript/module-model_baseMessage-BaseMessage.html

The message classes include their own buildFromSerializedData methods that may help in rebuilding the state should you need to do so.